# WPF: DataGridComboBoxColumn styling ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have this style defined in `<UserControl.Resources>`:

```
<Style x:Name="DropDownStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,2,2,2" Text="{Binding ID, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,2,10,2" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

which is used to display the items of the ComboBoxItem as `1 Car`, `2 Truck`, etc.

I would like to know how to move this style within the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` item as this style is being applied to all my other `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

I cannot figure out how to get down to the `ComboBoxItem` element of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to apply the style.

Comment: I guess you only want to apply that style to ComboBoxes in that specific DataGrid. In this case remove the `x:Name` of your style and move the style to the resources of the DataGrid `<DataGrid.Resources>`. The drawback is it changes all ComboBoxes in all columns.

Comment: @gomi42 Thanks for the suggestion but the other DataGridComboBoxColumns are within the same DataGrid so moving the style within the DataGrid will not work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I see. You can accomplish what you want in the following way. Keep the existing `ComboBoxItem` style where it is. Add another style for a Combobox, in the example below it is `MyComboBoxStyle´ and refore to the`EditingElementStyle´ in your `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

```
<Style x:Key="MyComboboxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource DropDownStyle}"/>
</Style>


<DataGridComboBoxColumn EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MyComboboxStyle}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding MySelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyArray}">
```